# Delete navigationDrawer top "shadow"

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar

i need to delete the shadow that shows when i open the navigationdrawer, i want to see my ActionBar (Its a v21 appcompat toolbar completly).

This is a screenshot to know my problem:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.firext.android.activities.work.WorkActivity">
```

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.firext.android.activities.work.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        tools:layout="@layout/work_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: did you solve this? if yes let me know how you did it

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to be using the Toolbar? If you are just using it exactly like the ActionBar why not use the ActionBar itself? The problem will be fixed then.

The other solution I can think of is to show the drawer on top of the Toolbar, which is the way it's supposed to be as stated in the design guidelines: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-side-nav-1